# IAM Permissions issue in API Gateway Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iam, api-gateway

AWS threw a below error saying the user doesn't have access to `apigateway:TagResource` permission, but when I checklist of available permissions in the IAM console, I'm not able to find any such permission.

```
xxxx is not authorized to perform: apigateway:TagResource on resource xxx
```

Currently, I've given the below permissions for that API.

```json
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "apigateway:DELETE",
        "apigateway:PUT",
        "apigateway:PATCH",
        "apigateway:POST",
        "apigateway:GET"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/restapis*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/apikeys*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/usageplans*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/domainnames*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/tags*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/apis*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringLikeIfExists": {
            "apigateway:Request/apiName": "my-api*"
        }
    }
}
```

How to resolve this, any other permission is required?

Comment: Remove the condition block and add the explicit name of resource specified in the error, and then ensure, to add tagResouces permission in the Action block, retry and lets see

Comment: there is no such permission like `apigateway:TagResource`, I'm struggling with it.

Comment: replace all this         "apigateway:DELETE",
        "apigateway:PUT",
        "apigateway:PATCH",
        "apigateway:POST",
        "apigateway:GET" with "apigateway:*" try and lets see

Comment: Yeah, i tried that earlier, it's working, but how to specify the required permission instead of wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dealing with a similar issue. Ultimately, the following worked for me:

```json
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "apigateway:POST",
    "apigateway:TagResource"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/apis",
    "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/apis/*/stages"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "aws:RequestTag/WbyProjectName": [
        "webiny-js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, but we'll get the below error in the I am policy visual editor right?


"Invalid Action: The action apigateway:TagResource does not exist."

did you just ignore that ?

Comment: @DilLip_Chowdary yea, I ignored it and it worked, I think the editor checker hasn't been updated to include newer actions